# Geting raw data from DDSM Mammogram database

Tags: matlab

While converting LJPEG mammogram images into readable raw data using Matlab I'm getting an error as follows:

```
Error using ==> pnmread at 25 C:\cygwin\case0001\C_0001_1.RIGHT_CC.1-ddsmraw2pnm.pnm: file does not exist.  
Error in ==> ConvertDDSMImageToRaw at 26 image = pnmread(pnmFileName);  
Error in ==>  ConvertDDSMImageToRaw(filename, columns, rows, digitizer);
```

Can anyone help to rectify this problem?

Comment: This appears to be a straightforward case of the non-existence of the file the program is looking for, or possibly a case of the file existing in a location other than the one the program is looking in.  Are you certain that neither of these applies to your case ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if the routine `pnmread` is by default looking for a '.pnm' file. You *may* be passing a filename header without an extension (perhaps because you attached 'pnm' rather than '.pnm' to the name header) and the routine assumes it is then a header you are passing and automatically appends '.png' to it. Look into the lines where you are putting together the filename that is being passed, and make sure the proper extension is being added, that is, make sure '.pnm', not just 'pnm', is being attached.